# Scroll iFrame onClick - JS or JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, scroll, onclick

So, I am trying to make a system which when you click an image (the button) the iFrame will scroll down to a certain point, I don´t want something that will scroll down/up but something that will scroll down/up TO A CERTAIN POINT. Someone who can help me? -USING

Images that will have the link:

```
<table height="424px" width="288px">
    <tr><td><img onclick="AutocastRoll()" name="imgcast1" id="imgcast1" src="Img/cast1img.png"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><img name="imgcast2" id="imgcast2" src="Img/cast2img.png" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><img name="imgcast3" id="imgcast3" src="Img/cast3img.png" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><img name="imgcast4" id="imgcast4" src="Img/cast4img.png" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

And the iFrame which will scrolls on click:

```
<div id="iFrameAutocast">
    <iframe name="iframepopup" id="iframepopup" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="376px" height="439px" src="iFrameAutocast1.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

ps.: The iFrame would scroll to the Y=437px and the X remain the same

Comment: Please mention and provide the code about what you have done until now.

Comment: I provided everything that I think will be necessary.

Comment: Please provide the Javascript code of "AutocastRoll()"

Comment: exactly, there is nothing in this function, I would like to know what to put there or maybe remove it and create a jQuery action...

Answer (score 0):

does this help you? Let me know if it works!

http://eppand.com/use-jquery-to-scroll-to-anchor-in-an-iframe/